# How to handle Postgres connection pooling in Vercel serverless functions? (“too many connections for role”)

Tags: postgresql, apollo, next.js, vercel

I have a small hobby web app built on this template: https://github.com/tomsoderlund/nextjs-pwa-graphql-sql-boilerplate

It uses ElephantSQL’s free tier (5 connections), runs on Zeit Now v2 serverless functions – and keeps running out of Postgres connections (“**too many connections for role "djsktctf"**”).

I’m using the `death` NPM to close connections - this is in `/api/graphql/index.js`:

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-micro')
const { config } = require('../../config/config')

// Postgres (pg)
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const onProcessDeath = require('death')
const pool = new Pool({ connectionString: config.databaseUrl })
let client

const initDatabaseClient = async () => {
  if (!client) client = await pool.connect()
}
initDatabaseClient()

onProcessDeath((signal, err) => {
  client && client.release()
})

const typeDefs = gql`
  ${require('../../graphql/font/schema')}
`

const resolvers = {
  ...require('../../graphql/font/resolvers')(pool)
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  introspection: true,
  playground: true
})

module.exports = server.createHandler({ path: config.graphqlPath })
```

Then inside `resolvers` it looks like this:

```
module.exports = (pool) => ({
  Query: {
    async articles (parent, variables, context, info) {
      const sqlString = `SELECT * FROM article LIMIT 100;`
      const { rows } = await pool.query(sqlString)
      return rows
    }
}
```

How can I improve this to avoid running out of connections?

### Update

After getting the answer below, I updated my code with `client.end()` and NOT using a shared client:

```
// const results = await runDatabaseFunction(async (pool) => { ... })
const runDatabaseFunction = async function (functionToRun) {
  // Connect db
  const client = await pool.connect()
  // Run function
  const results = await functionToRun(client)
  // Release db
  await client.end()
  await client.release()
  return results
}
```

Comment: just curious about your pool config - mind sharing it? Do you have max, min, acquire & idle set? Have you experimented with retry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that problem comes from
`client = await pool.connect()`

It seems to hold your DB. So you need to disconnect something between you and DB.

If you add `await client.end()` after your last data fetching, then the error may go away.

In my case, this way solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I'm now using both `client.end()` AND `client.release()`: `const client = await pool.connect(); const results = await client.query(sqlString, paramArray); await client.end(); await client.release();` although the official docs seem to state that `end()` is for the entire pool: https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling